# How to sort an arraylist based on last character in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have an an array list that display each unique word of a string and the amount of times they occur(each element is a String)
But I want to sort the array list based on the last character which is the count, is there a method to do this?

**Example**:

```
"it was the best of times it was the worst of times"
was - 2
best - 1
it - 2
the - 2
times - 2
of - 2
worst - 1
```

**Expected Output:**

```
it - 2
of - 2
times - 2
the - 2
was - 2
best - 1
worst - 1
```

Comment: Last character? Your Question seems to contradict the example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could pass in a lambda to [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)):

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "it was the best of times it was the worst of times";
        List<String> wordsWithCounts = getWordsWithCountsFromSentence(sentence);

        System.out.println("Before sorting on counts then alphabetically:");
        System.out.println(wordsWithCounts);

        wordsWithCounts.sort((s1, s2) -> {
            String[] s1Split = s1.split(" ");
            String[] s2Split = s2.split(" ");
            String s1Count = s1Split.length != 0 ? s1Split[s1Split.length - 1] : "";
            String s2Count = s2Split.length != 0 ? s2Split[s2Split.length - 1] : "";
            if (!s1Count.equals(s2Count)) {
                return s2Count.compareTo(s1Count); // decreasing order based on counts
            }
            return s1.compareTo(s2); // alphabetically otherwise if same counts
        });

        System.out.println("After sorting on counts then alphabetically:");
        System.out.println(wordsWithCounts);
    }

    private static List<String> getWordsWithCountsFromSentence(String sentence) {
        Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // To maintain insertion order for before output
        for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
            wordCounts.put(word, wordCounts.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
        }
        return wordCounts.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> String.join(" - ", entry.getKey(), String.valueOf(entry.getValue())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before sorting on counts then alphabetically:
[it - 2, was - 2, the - 2, best - 1, of - 2, times - 2, worst - 1]
After sorting on counts then alphabetically:
[it - 2, of - 2, the - 2, times - 2, was - 2, best - 1, worst - 1]
```

**N.B.** The difference between the above output and your expected output is because `the` comes before `times` lexiographically, which the above code defaults to if the counts are the same.